# Why Can't I use a mem_fn Functor in bind?

Tags: c++, c++11, bind, functor, mem-fun

I wanted to pass a `mem_fn` argument to `bind` but the compiler doesn't seem to allow it.

For example this works fine:

```
accumulate(cbegin(foos), cend(foos), 0, bind(plus<int>(), placeholders::_1, bind(&foo::r, placeholders::_2)));
```

But when I try to use the `mem_fn` functor I get about a page of errors:

```
accumulate(cbegin(foos), cend(foos), 0, bind(plus<int>(), placeholders::_1, mem_fn(&foo::r)));
```

> /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_numeric.h: In instantiation of ‘_Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Tp = int; _BinaryOperation = std::_Bind(std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Mem_fn)>]’:
>   prog.cpp:20:102:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_numeric.h:154:22: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind(std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Mem_fn)>) (int&, foo* const&)’

Comment: You are the first person I see using `bind`'s special handling for nested bind expressions without knowing it.

Comment: mem_fn is deprecated, don't use it.

Comment: @n.m. It is?  I know the typedefs inside it will be in C++17 but I don't see anything about the `mem_fn` itself being deprecated.

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry got it confused with mem_fun.

Comment: @n.m. Ah.  Yeah, they didn't make that the easiest to keep straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand this, think about what it would mean if you just passed a literal to `bind`'s 3<sup>rd</sup> argument. For Example if you had done:

```
accumulate(cbegin(foos), cend(foos), 0, bind(plus<int>(), placeholders::_1, 13))
```

The result would have been `size(foos) * 13`, because `plus` would have used `13` as it's addend on each iteration.

```
accumulate(cbegin(foos), cend(foos), 0, bind(plus<int>(), placeholders::_1, mem_fn(&foo::r)))
```

Won't compile because it's attempting to pass the result of `mem_fn(&foo::r)` as the addend to `plus`. Since that can't be converted to an `int` `plus` can't accept that. But even if it could be converted to an `int`, that's not what you're looking for, you want to take the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument and call `foo::r` on it, passing the result to `plus`. Thus we know we need to see, `placeholders::_2` used somewhere in the statement, conveying the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument for the calling of it's `r` method.

---

We need to bind `placeholders::_2` to be bound to a functor which will call the `r` method on it's parameter. The binding will of course require `bind`, but actually [`bind` can take a method as it's 1<sup>st</sup> argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind#Parameters).

That said, the `bind(&foo::r, placeholders::_2)` statement from your working code doesn't make any sense in non-nested form; that functor doesn't even take 2 parameters! [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) actually has [special rules for handling a `bind` nested within another `bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind#Member_function_operator.28.29), so that they can share the outer `bind`'s placeholders, lest there be no way to convey a bound argument to a nested expression:

> If the stored argument arg is of type `T` for which `std::is_bind_expression<T>::value == true` (for example, another `bind` expression was passed directly into the initial call to `bind`), then `bind` performs function composition: instead of passing the function object that the bind subexpression would return, the subexpression is invoked eagerly, and its return value is passed to the outer invokable object. If the `bind` subexpression has any placeholder arguments, they are shared with the outer `bind`.

---

The only way to use `mem_fn` in this expression would be to pass it it's result to `bind` for the conveying of `placeholders::_2`: `bind(mem_fn(&foo::r), placeholders::_2)` This works, but is an unnecessary step when the simple `bind(&foo::r, placeholders::_2)` will suffice. Thus the best way to generate this functor is either with your proffered statement:

```
accumulate(cbegin(foos), cend(foos), 0, bind(plus<int>(), placeholders::_1, bind(&foo::r, placeholders::_2)))
```

Or by using a lambda:

```
accumulate(cbegin(foos), cend(foos), 0, [](const int augend, const auto& addend) { return augend + addend.r(); } )
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, clearly, the second example doesn't mention `placeholders::_2`. When `accumulate` calls the functor with two arguments, the second argument is ignored, and your code is trying to add up an `int` and an instance of the internal class that `mem_fn` returns.

I suggest you drop all these `bind` games, and use a lambda:

```
accumulate(cbegin(foos), cend(foos), 0, 
    [](int val, foo* f) { return val + f->r(); });
```

Much clearer what's going on here.